# How to Create a Conditional Segue

Tags: xcode4.3

I have created a project in Xcode using storyboards. I created a segue between two of the view controllers with a button using the click and drag method. However, there are a certain set of conditions that I want to be met in order for the segue to happen.  So I already coded the button as an IB action and wrote the conditional code in the implementation file. If the conditions are not met, an alert view pops up, and I don't want the segue to happen. But if the conditions are met then I do want the segue to happen.

Is there any way to programmatically command a segue to happen or not happen inside an IB action function? Or any other way to get the same kind of result?

THANKS! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great solution for this that someone posted... create a segue that originates from from the status bar of the originating view controller, give it an identifier, and then add this code inside the action button:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifierName" sender:sender];
```

Works great!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom segue by subclassing UIStoryboardSegue and setting the segue style to "custom" along with your class name in the attributes inspector. Then you can override the perform method in order to see if your conditions are met before you perform the segue. For example

```
- (void) perform {
    if (...) {
        [[self sourceViewController] presentModalViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:YES];
    }
}
```

See also the documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html

Alternatively, you could disable the button as long as your conditions are not met. Maybe that's the better approach, since then the user has a visual indication that the segue won't happen, instead of getting a negative feedback after pressing the button.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I'm fairly new to this - could you elaborate a bit? I created a subclass of the storyboardSegue, and I know that I'm going to have something in the implementation file like:-(void) perform {
    //conditional code, then segue yes or no...
}    but I'm not sure how to write code that tells the controller to segue or not segue

Comment: Added a basic code example. There are many resources on how to create custom segues available in the web, also in stackoverflow.