# Pass variable returned Object via Segue depending on which button pressed

Tags: ios, swift, segue, swift4, uistoryboardsegue

I have a `WorkoutGenerator` struct which returns different workouts based on different parameters, for example  `generateWorkout.standardWorkout` returns something different to `generateWorkout.hardWorkout`.

I have 3 buttons on a 'Workout Setup' page, each meant to pass a different type of workout to the 'Workout Page' (there is also an input field for 'workout time').

I have currently have one segue `goToWorkout` from "Workout Setup Page" to "Workout Page"

What I want to do, is trigger the `segue` to the workout page, passing the different workouts depending on what the user presses.

So far I have :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    //currently have one segue between the pages
    if segue.identifier == "goToWorkout" {

        let finalTimeForWorkout = Int(timeInputField.text!)              
        //set a standardWorkout to pass to Workout Page
        let finalWorkout = FinalWorkout(generatedWorkout: WorkoutGenerator.standardWorkout.generate(), timeForWorkout: finalTimeForWorkout!)

        //set the final parameters ready to pass
        let finalWorkoutTime = finalWorkout.timeForWorkout
        let finalWorkoutExercises = finalWorkout.generatedWorkout.workoutExercises

        if let destVC = segue.destination as? WorkoutController {
            destVC.selectedWorkoutExerciseArray = finalWorkoutExercises
            destVC.selectedWorkoutTime = finalWorkoutTime

        }
    }
}  

and then something like this for each button :

//use this button to pass a standard workout
//want to pass a diff workout if a diff button pressed
@IBAction func standardWorkoutPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToWorkout", sender: self )
}
```

My problem after playing around with it for a few hours is how to **elegantly** pass a different workout to the workout page.

i.e. I guess I could literally just copy and paste all the code for each button and make a new segue for each but that seems like the wrong way to do it!

The sort of thing I've tried is defining the workouts as variables in an `if` `else if` section but then the final workouts are out of scope for the segue.

Hope this makes sense, answers I can find about conditional segues seem to mostly refer to 'only allow the segue to happen under this condition' rather than pass different data sets to the same destination. e.g. [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947328/conditional-segue-using-storyboard) and [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654097/how-to-create-a-conditional-segue)

Comment: I take it that you know which workout the user selected when the buttons are tapped? If so, just store this workout in a property when the button is tapped and access it later when doing the segue, passing it to the target viewcontroller

Comment: I just had a quick skim, a bit of advice - your question has a lot of context specific detail, when you're asking about a pretty generic concept. I think you could make your question a quarter of the length and complexity.

Comment: thanks @Peza i will make sure I do this in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add my comment as an answer instead, to make it easier to show some code examples.

Add a property to your viewcontroller:

```
var selectedWorkout : FinalWorkout!
```

in each of your three button action methods you set this property to the workout associated with each button. So for your standard workout:

```
@IBAction func standardWorkoutPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let finalTimeForWorkout = Int(timeInputField.text!)

    self.selectedWorkout = FinalWorkout(generatedWorkout: WorkoutGenerator.standardWorkout.generate(), timeForWorkout: finalTimeForWorkout!)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToWorkout", sender: self )
}
```

Finally:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToWorkout" {
        let finalWorkoutTime = selectedWorkout.timeForWorkout
        let finalWorkoutExercises = selectedWorkout.generatedWorkout.workoutExercises
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? WorkoutController {
            destVC.selectedWorkoutExerciseArray = finalWorkoutExercises
            destVC.selectedWorkoutTime = finalWorkoutTime
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: this solution works - but it loads one screen with a workout on it and then loads another one straight after.  The first one is the right one and the second one is wrong when I click on standard but the opposite is true when I click on 'repeaterWorkout' - do you know why might this be?

Comment: i had 2 segues triggering from the button my fault!

Answer (score 1):

In `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`, `sender` can be anything you like.

Use `sender` to pass the generated workout to `performSegue`:

```
//use this button to pass a standard workout
//want to pass a diff workout if a diff button pressed
@IBAction func standardWorkoutPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToWorkout", sender: WorkoutGenerator.standardWorkout.generate() )

}
```

Then in `prepare(for:sender:)`

```
let finalWorkout = FinalWorkout(generatedWorkout: sender as! YourWorkoutGeneratorType, timeForWorkout: finalTimeForWorkout!)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have this right, you want to pass a different argument into your `FinalWorkout()` function based on which button was pressed?

It doesn't always make for very readable code, but you can use the UIButton `tag` property. If you set each button's tag property to a unique value [0, 1, 2], you can use that info to generate a different workout:

```
// This code would be in: override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
let buttonTag = (sender as! UIButton).tag

if buttonTag == 0 { // Generate type of workout}
else if buttonTag == 1 { // Generate type of workout }
else if buttonTag == 2 { // Generate type of workout }
```

Or if you're worried about tags not being an intuitive representation, you could just test for equality with the IBOutlet reference you have for each button:

```
let buttonPressed = sender as! UIButton

if (buttonPressed == self.yourButtonIBOutletPropertyName) { // select a workout for this button}
```

I may have missed what you were asking, if this is the case comment and I'll update the answer.